# height method of jquery is not working for me?

Tags: jquery, css

I have written a height method of jquery for a site. But it is not working. I can't understand what is going wrong with this. If you can please help me. I have attached an image and from this you can understand everything. I have used the following code for this but not working. Here is the real site [link](http://debtorfinanceguide.com/). Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var cHeight = $('#block-4').outerHeight(true);
    $('#block-57').css("min-height","cHeight");
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

cHeight is variable not string

```
$('#block-57').find('ul').content().css("min-height",cHeight);
```

Comment: Right. I have changed my question as well as used the right answer and now working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would work better without the quotes around `cHeight` (otherwise javascript just read a string, not a variable):

```
$('#block-57').find('ul').content().css("min-height",cHeight);
```